# TableView is empty when used inside ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a class named as

```
@interface Appointment : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>

{
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellName;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellPhone;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellEmail;
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellType;

    IBOutlet UITextField* txtName;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtPhone;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtEmail;
    IBOutlet UITextField* txtType;

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;


}
```

IN MY storyboard, the view controller has an image on top , a bar and below it is tableView. I have also wired tableView. The tableViewCells of tableview show just fine but when i Run code whole screen is just blank

1- Why is my TableView not showing cells
2- How can I set an image to background of TableView instead of Default

Best Regards

Comment: How to you load the table view and the view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you didn't bind the `tableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets to your `Appointment` view controller to let the tableview know which object is gonna feed it (with the cells using `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and other `UITableViewDataSource` methods).

Comment: you can win the bit if you can tell how can i do that :)

Comment: In your storyboard, just right-click-and-drag from your `TableView` to your `Appointment` ViewController, and bind the two mentioned outlets. Actually exactly like you would do to bind any other outlet of one object to another from Interface Builder (i.e. like you did to bind your `Appointment`'s "`tableView`" IBOutlet to your tableView, but this time in the other order, to bind not an IBOutlet of `Appointment` (namely `tableView`) to an object (the tableview) but bind IBOutlets of the tableView (namely `dataSource` and `delegate`) to an object (your ViewController that implement the methods)

Comment: I am starting to get this error after linking delegate and datasource of tableView to my ViewController terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Seems normal to me, this means that now your dataSource methods are called whereas they were not called before, so you're in the right path. But you probably didn't implement your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` dataSource method correctly, so in some cases (maybe all) your method returns `nil` (nothing) instead of returning a `UITableViewCell`. So you have to fix this by implementing the method correctly.

Comment: And for more info your should really read [the dedocated Programming Guide in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html). Everything is explained in here.